# Can Thor not sense other superpowered beings?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, avengers-infinity-war

From *Avengers: Infinity War*:

> Quill: Wait, what kinda weapon are we talking about here?
>
> Thor: The Thanos-killing kind.
>
> Quill: Don't you think that we should all have a
>   weapon like that?
>
> Thor: No. You simply lack the strength to wield
>   them. Your bodies would crumble as your minds collapsed into madness.

Of course Quill is part-Celestial and has been shown to handle an Infinity Stone directly. He is inexperienced in the use of his powers as he only discovered his true nature a few years previously, but he is potentially as powerful as Thor, if not more so. But Thor is completely oblivious to this.

Comment: i don't think ego was an actual celestial

Comment: What leads you to believe Thor should be able to sense other superpowered beings?

Comment: Because he is able to see through Loki's disguises

Comment: @Gaius I think he just learns over the course of the MCU that Loki generally "isn't there". He does't see through them he thinks something isn't quite right and that generally leads to Loki putting up a disguise.

Comment: @Gaius - He spends a lot of time throwing things at Loki to determine if he's real or not

Comment: And didn't Quill lose his powers as a result of the events of GotG2?

Comment: @DanielRoseman It indicates he can't use them anymore with the power fading. However, with my speculation hat on, I'd say he still can use them he's just got to go within himself and not to Ego's core.

Comment: There's at least one way in which Peter Quill is clearly inferior to Thor: arrogance.  Thor has everyone beat in that regard...

Comment: You're assuming here that the type of power in stormbraker is the same as that of the powerstone. Using an appropriate analogy perhaps Quill is like a ceramic pipe able to transfer large amounts of hydraulic energy (cosmic power) but unable to transfer electricity (Asguardian magic). Just speculation of course

Comment: I am not sure it makes sense that Quill's power disappeared with Ego. If it was Ego's power all along, why did he need a *second* Celestial in order to carry out his plan? It only makes sense if Quill can generate his own power too. He just doesn't know how to without Ego to guide him.

Comment: Quill lost his Celestial powers when Ego died in *Guardians of the Galaxy 2*.. Yes, I read your previous comment, but do you really know how science of Celestial power works?

Comment: We're a bunch of mortals huddled together thinking Quill's Celestial/Ego power is plenty damn spiffy.  But on the levels of power discussed in the scene/quote, perhaps Thor has assessed Quill's potential with 100% accuracy.  Or, put another way, Quill might be like a snappy sports car, but the job requires a Caterpillar D11 bulldozer.

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe he can but I'm not aware of any explicit answer on this. To answer this though I will look through your analysis.

***"Of course Quill is part-Celestial and has been shown to handle an Infinity Stone directly."***

True, however, had the other Guardians not been there it would have destroyed him. It was with their collective strength that they could keep the stone's power at bay, not solely Quill's. You can see it destroying Quill in the scene on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TQcFJ2KYjmU).

[image: Star Lord holds the Power Stone]

Gamora alludes to the fact the stone would have killed him had he held on to it alone when Nova Prime tells them about his father.

> **Corpsman Dey:** When we arrested you, we noticed an anomaly in your nervous system, so we had it checked out.
>
> **Peter Quill:** I'm not Terran?
>
> **Nova Prime:** You are half Terran. Your mother was of earth. Your father, well, he's something very ancient we've never seen here before.
>
> **Gamora:** That could be why you were able to hold the stone for as long as you did.
>
> <sub>*Guardians of the Galaxy*</sub>

***"He is inexperienced in the use of his powers as he only discovered his true nature a few years previously"***

There's no indication Quill still has his Celestial powers. In fact it even points to him not having them anymore as we see in the official script when Ego is destroyed.

> *He looks down at his hands, where the glow FADES and DISAPPEARS.*
>
> <sub>*Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2*</sub>

***"he is potentially as powerful as Thor, if not more so"***

Looking at the above I don't think this is accurate, Thor seems to be a lot more powerful than Quill is.

---

And from the comments:

***"What leads you to believe Thor should be able to sense other superpowered beings?" "Because he is able to see through Loki's disguises"***

Not really, the few times he sees through his actual disguises without throwing something at him is when it's obvious something isn't quite right: for example, in the cell on Asgard and when Loki is disguised as Odin. Note that before this time at the end of *Thor: The Dark World* Thor believes the Odin he sees is Odin and not Loki.

The rest of the times Thor "sees" through the disguise is by throwing objects at Loki. This is, however, to check if he's there or not as is evident throughout of *Thor: Ragnarok*.

> **LOKI:** Surprise.
>
> *Thor TOSSES a bottle. It BOUNCES off of Loki’s head.*
>
> **LOKI:** OW!
>
> **THOR:** Just had to be sure.
>
> <sub>*Thor: Ragnarok*</sub>

---

Lastly, and quite importantly, to provide some context to the scene in *Avengers: Infinity War*. Thor and Quill are clearly sizing each other up and having a boasting match about who is more manly. This could just be another way for Thor to say he is better than Quill without even knowing… remember Thor likely thinks Quill is completely Terran at this point.